# $P$-value for testing an inequality?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I may just be searching up the wrong thing but I can't find anything for this online. Let's say I want to get a $p$ value for the hypothesis that $$\mu > \mu_0$$ for a population mean parameter. How do I go about getting a $p$ value? The way I thought this was done was by getting a test statistic (which in this case does not have an absolute value sign afaik):$$d = \frac{\hat{\mu} - \mu_0}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

And then getting the $p$ value by calculating ($\sigma$ is known in this case):
$$p = \Pr(D < d), D \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

What's wrong here, and how do I calculate the $p$ value?

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there. The p-value is the probability of the queue

$$p_{value}=P(D<d)$$

and you can get it using Z-tables

---

Example:

Suppose we have the following system to be verified:

$$
\begin{cases}
H_0:\mu \geq2 \\
H_1: \mu<2
\end{cases}$$

let's suppose normality, $\sigma=1$,$n=4$.

The sample mean should be less then 2, otherwise there is nothing to prove and the p-value will be very high.

So let's suppose $\overline{X}_4=1$

Your statistic is

$(1-2)\times \sqrt{4}=-2$

and the p-value is $P(Z<-2)\approx2.28\%$

Comment: Thanks for the help, was stuck on this for a while. Now that I have that, how exactly would I know do make it greater than and not less than in the future? What's the reason behind it being > and not <? In my lecture notes for the class I'm taking, the prof showed it can be D < d, D > d or D > |d| in different cases, which is where I chose < from.

Comment: @S.M. sorry, it's correct <. If you are testing a null Hypothesis $\mu>\mu_0$ the data must contraddict it, so you sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ must be less than $\mu_0$

Comment: I'm still stuck then... The exact question from my assignment was the above situation, but we are given a p value of 0.54, a estimated mean and hypothesis mean and must calculate the standard error.

Comment: @SM : Edited my answer with a simple example

Comment: Strictly speaking null hypothesis must have an $=$-sign, whether as $=. \le,$ or $\ge.$ The equality is used to compute the null distribution.